# scale_x_datetime any way to not make small segments disappear?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot where "time2" of the first entry is "2012-04-04 09:23:36" and because the segment is so small it does not appear on the chart. Is there a way to make the first segement ending at "2012-04-04 09:23:36" show up in some way so that it doesn't appear like it does not exist? Also I need 10 minute bins.

Thank you.

```
 library(scales)
df = data.frame(time1=as.POSIXct(c("2012-04-04 09:23:33","2012-04-04 10:24:55")),
                  time2=as.POSIXct(c("2012-04-04 09:23:36","2012-04-04 18:42:24")), 
                  y1=c(1,2),
                  y2=c(1,2),
                  color = c("red","blue"))
ggplot(df)  + geom_segment(aes(x = time1, y = y1, xend = time2, yend = y2), 
             colour= df$color, size = 4, data = df)+
    scale_x_datetime( breaks=date_breaks("10 min"), labels=date_format("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: even with %H:%M:%S the segement does not appear -- please see updated question

Comment: You are trying to showing a segment 7 seconds long on an axis with a range of over 15 thousand seconds.  It may be that the scale is just too large for a line that small to be discernible.

Comment: Yes - I'm looking for a way to show those small segements